# What is the story of Worldbuilding's beginnings

Tags: discussion

I hear moderator candidates talking about being around since it was on Area 51, etc.  **What's the story of WB's start, its naming, and its earliest definition(s)?**

Answer (score 4):

Most of that history can be seen on the Area51 site here:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding

The actual origin of the name and the site I don't think anyone can answer since the person who originally proposed it hasn't been around since before it even went into beta.

We started with definition:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276?phase=definition

Then I joined during commitment:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276?phase=commitment

And then there was the beta:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276?phase=beta

During the private beta we worked to define the site's scope, and then during the public beta we worked to prove that the site had longevity and purpose.

Comment: "During the closed beta we worked to define the site's scope". I'd like to see some documentation on that.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Just go back in time and look at the first meta posts on the site :)

Comment: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions?page=40&sort=newest

Comment: See that page plus most of the next few pages too... (Note to anyone coming to this late - those pages will most likely move, just go to the oldest pages :)

Comment: Thanks, I can't really contact people directly (understandably), but I was hoping that I or someone could do a post to our blog about the history of it - If I'm able to compile it, shall I attach it as an answer here to my question first?

Comment: @Mikey That's a really cool idea, I'd like to read it. Whether you post it here is up to you. The best plan will be to talk to people in the blog chatroom though http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory

Answer (score 3):

I can provide some details on the real early area 51 activity.  After Kexx proposed it the proposal was actually shut down.  The description and scope were virtually non-existent. Myself, [rbwhitaker](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/52171/rbwhitaker) (who I believe made an appearance here at one point) and a couple others lobbied Robert Cartaino for a few days and got him to open the proposal back up.

After that we reworked the description and got working on making the sample questions better and kept it open, it gathered steam rather quickly as far as proposals go...and the rest they say is history.